# HubConnection::Start().Wait() times out if behind web proxy

Tags: signalr.client

Without a web proxy, Start().Wait() works fine. Connection trace:

```
11:31:15.0221694 - null - ChangeState(Disconnected, Connecting)
11:31:17.1749694 - 054a636a-10dc-4d39-a77b-709639ea4e5f - SSE: GET http://<removed>/signalr/connect?transport=serverSentEvents&connectionToken=TFuti92AamDL%2FsFNOE8LF1N6T10bDcosIqdkmHbLxYpPwNtW9szZNHHDkrLPR1mFa0Pu%2FUgqmU6fkA%2Fh6iuOY9tTMfjfwqwa%2F5vpZk%2B9iuESgPD5OFYZelTG%2FZn16USK&connectionData=[{"Name":"myHub"}]
11:31:17.9549694 - 054a636a-10dc-4d39-a77b-709639ea4e5f - ChangeState(Connecting, Connected)
```

But behind a web proxy, it times out or returns after a long time (4-5 minutes) if `TransportConnectTimeout` is increased. Connection trace:

```
05:04:05.4397657 - null - ChangeState(Disconnected, Connecting)
05:04:06.1727657 - 7d8ed176-4ca7-461b-97bb-d32b2e71d950 - SSE: GET http://<removed>/signalr/connect?transport=serverSentEvents&connectionToken=Q0FllYmOPNl0%2BQqI643N%2Bzed2zuNAEvLywMLnqkPV4H6%2BPMaiwlrEYGJsNBvrG8QMWdnEJh%2B0qf5UBDj1rpp9JNktaISXa4vhwpK6KnUo32R6d4vBEgunh9Ju%2FRZTm%2Bu&connectionData=[{"Name":"myHub"}]
05:04:11.1737657 - 7d8ed176-4ca7-461b-97bb-d32b2e71d950 - Auto: Failed to connect to using transport serverSentEvents. System.TimeoutException: Transport timed out trying to connect
05:04:11.1837657 - 7d8ed176-4ca7-461b-97bb-d32b2e71d950 - LP Connect: http://<removed>/signalr/connect
05:04:11.8147657 - 7d8ed176-4ca7-461b-97bb-d32b2e71d950 - ChangeState(Connecting, Connected)
05:04:11.8217657 - 7d8ed176-4ca7-461b-97bb-d32b2e71d950 - LP Poll: http://<removed>/signalr/poll
```

So if behind the web proxy, SignalR fails to connect with SSE protocol and falls back to long polling and connects in about 5 seconds, but still Start().Wait() does not return.

So, how to get it working behind a web proxy? I am using SignalR version 2.0.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a workaround: Instead of waiting on `Start()`, handle the `HubConnection.StateChanged` event. This event is fired on time.